# How complicate could the shaders be in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

If I have a very complicate geometry shader, is there a limit of memory footprint for the codes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shaders are not limited by "complexity", but by *runtime*. If a shader executes for too long, the GPU/OS will assume that the shader has entered an infinite loop and kill the shader's execution (and probably the application that launched it). How long that is depends on the GPU and possibly the shader stage.

Comment: Don't even modern GPUs have upper limits on the number of instructions in a given program?

Comment: @genpfault: Maybe, but 1) there's no way to map GLSL or even SPIR-V code to "number of instructions" (unrolling, inlining, and the like are completely out of your control), so if a limit exists, you have no control over it, and 2) that limit is going to be pretty large, relative to the execution time limit on rendering shaders.